# Order and product measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n$ are $\sigma$-finite measures, there exist a unique $\sigma$-finite measure $\pi$ on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}_1\otimes\dots \otimes\mathcal{A}_n$ in $\Omega_1\times \dots \times \Omega_n$with the property that

$$\pi(A_1\times\dots\times A_n)=\mu_1(A_1)\cdot ... \cdot\mu_n(A_n)  \hspace{1cm} \text{for all  } A_j\in \mathcal{A}_j \hspace{0.2cm} 1\leq j\leq n$$

$\pi$ is called the product of the measures $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n$ and is denoted $\mu_1\otimes\dots \otimes\mu_n$.

Suppose instead I consider an arbitrary finite index set $I$ and the space $\times_{i\in I}\Omega_i$ of all maps $f:I\to \bigcup_{i\in I} \Omega_i$ such that $f(i)\in \Omega_i$ for each $i\in I$. I define $\bigotimes_{i\in I}\mathcal{A}_i$ has the $\sigma$-algebra on $\times_{i\in I}\Omega_i$ generated by the sets $\times_{i\in I}A_i$ with $A_i\in \mathcal{A}_i \hspace{0.2cm} 1\leq i\leq n$.  Then I can use the same approach as above to prove the existence and uniqueness of a measure $\pi$ on $\bigotimes_{i\in I}\mathcal{A}_i$ with the property that

$$\pi(\times_{i\in I}A_i)=\prod_{i\in I}\mu_i(A_i)\hspace{1cm} \text{for all  } A_i\in \mathcal{A}_i \hspace{0.2cm} 1\leq i\leq n$$

and denote this measure by $\bigotimes_{i\in I}\mu_i$.

Clearly if $I=\{1,\dots,n\}$ then the two constructions are identical (except that in the second one I use a space of functions rather than ordered tuples). But in the second one it is clear that order doesn't matter, while in the first one I choose a specific order.

My question is why do we choose an order when working with a finite product of measures. Is it only for concreteness, or is there a benefit of doing so?

I got this question when looking at the construction of an infinite product of probability spaces, where we use the second approach.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a note. The product algebra is generated by sets of the form $\times_{i\in I} A_i$, where each $A_i$ is measurable, and $A_i=\Omega_i$ *for all but a finite number* of $i$'s (of course, using intersections, you can extend this $A_i$ being non-trivial for at most countably many $i$). This is the natural definition when you want to define it as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra making all the coordinate projections measurable.

Comment: As far as the ordering goes, there's always an order in the sense that it doesn't a priori make sense to exchange $A_i$ and $A_j$, since $\Omega_i$ and $\Omega_j$ are two distinct sets. That being said, to the extend that you can reasonably swap $A_i$ and $A_j$ and $\mu_i=\mu_j$, then obviously, the "order" never matters for either definition.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I mean $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ is not the same set as $\Omega_2 \times \Omega_1$ if $\Omega_1 \neq \Omega_2$, but $\times_{i\in I}\Omega_i$ is the same whether $I=\{1,2\}$ or  $I=\{2,1\}$ no?

Comment: Well... what do you mean? As sets, $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ are the same.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Exactly so in the second approach order doesn't play a role, but it does in the first one.

Comment: Usually, finite products are defined as ordered tuples rather than maps from some index set to some disjoint union. I guess that's where your confusion lies. However, claiming that order plays a role seems a bit disingenuous to me. I mean... there is a very clear, perfectly natural isomorphism between $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$ and $\Omega_2\times \Omega_1$ (as sets, measure spaces, what have you).

Comment: @WoolierThanThou True, so I guess we do this for concreteness.